# Merge three dataframe, count the matches and add new columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 3 dataframes `(df1, df2, df3)` i want to merge these dataframe based on a column and add two new columns. one column should say which dataframes are matching, second how many of them matched.

```
# df1
data = {'ID': ["M1", "M2", "M3", "M4"],
        'Movie': ["Top gun", "Thor", "Batman", "MadMax"],
        'Actor' : ["Tom", "Chris", "Bale", "Tom"],
        'type': ["Action", "SciFi", "Comic", "SciFi"]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

# df2
data = {'ID': ["M1", "M2", "M3"],
        'highlight': ["Flight school", "Love and thunder", "I am Batman"]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

# df3
data = {'ID': ["M2", "M3"],
       'no of parts': [3, 3],
       'co-star' : ["portman", "neeson"],
       'award': ["yes", "yes"]}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Expected output will be**

[image]

The `match` and `no of match` are the new column

Thank you for your time

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) your three dataframes on `ID`, then use the `indicator` parameter to `merge` to determine which dataframes had valid data, using this info to generate the `match` column. You can then count the number of `|` characters in `match` to determine the `No of match` column:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': ["M1", "M2", "M3", "M4"], 'Movie': ["Top gun", "Thor", "Batman", "MadMax"], 'Actor' : ["Tom", "Chris", "Bale", "Tom"], 'type': ["Action", "SciFi", "Comic", "SciFi"]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

data = {'ID': ["M1", "M2", "M3"], 'highlight': ["Flight school", "Love and thunder", "I am Batman"]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

data = {'ID': ["M2", "M3"], 'no of parts': [3, 3], 'co-star' : ["portman", "neeson"], 'award': ["yes", "yes"]}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df1.merge(df2, on='ID', how='left', indicator='df1df2').merge(df3, on='ID', how='left',indicator='df3')
df['match'] = df['df1df2'].map({'both':'df1|df2', 'left_only':'df1'})+df['df3'].map({'both':'|df3', 'left_only':''})
df['No of match'] = df['match'].str.count('\|')+1

df = df.drop(['df1df2', 'df3'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   ID    Movie  Actor    type         highlight  no of parts  co-star award        match  No of match
0  M1  Top gun    Tom  Action     Flight school          NaN      NaN   NaN      df1|df2            2
1  M2     Thor  Chris   SciFi  Love and thunder          3.0  portman   yes  df1|df2|df3            3
2  M3   Batman   Bale   Comic       I am Batman          3.0   neeson   yes  df1|df2|df3            3
3  M4   MadMax    Tom   SciFi               NaN          NaN      NaN   NaN          df1            1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join and indicator `parameter`s for see `match`ed DataFrames, then use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for remove column with processing by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for dictionaries, append `df3` column with mapping another dictionary and last count `|` by [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html):

```
df = (df1.merge(df2, on='ID', how='left', indicator='df2')
         .merge(df3, on='ID', how='left', indicator='df3'))

df['match'] = (df.pop('df2').map({'both':'df1|df2', 'left_only':'df1'}) +
               df.pop('df3').map({'both':'|df3', 'left_only':''}))
df['No of match'] = df['match'].str.count('\|') + 1
print (df)
   ID    Movie  Actor    type         highlight  no of parts  co-star award  \
0  M1  Top gun    Tom  Action     Flight school          NaN      NaN   NaN   
1  M2     Thor  Chris   SciFi  Love and thunder          3.0  portman   yes   
2  M3   Batman   Bale   Comic       I am Batman          3.0   neeson   yes   
3  M4   MadMax    Tom   SciFi               NaN          NaN      NaN   NaN   

         match  No of match  
0      df1|df2            2  
1  df1|df2|df3            3  
2  df1|df2|df3            3  
3          df1            1
```

Another idea with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) for assign helper columns `df1-df3` filled by `True`s and for match columns use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html):

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

L = [df_.set_index('ID').assign(**{f'df{i}':True}) for i, df_ in enumerate(dfs, start=1)]
df = pd.concat(L, axis=1)

cols = df.filter(regex='^df\d').columns
df['match'] = df[cols].fillna(False).dot(cols + '|').str[:-1]
df['No of match'] = df['match'].str.count('\|') + 1
df = df.drop(cols, axis=1)
print (df)
      Movie  Actor    type         highlight  no of parts  co-star award  \
ID                                                                         
M1  Top gun    Tom  Action     Flight school          NaN      NaN   NaN   
M2     Thor  Chris   SciFi  Love and thunder          3.0  portman   yes   
M3   Batman   Bale   Comic       I am Batman          3.0   neeson   yes   
M4   MadMax    Tom   SciFi               NaN          NaN      NaN   NaN   

          match  No of match  
ID                            
M1      df1|df2            2  
M2  df1|df2|df3            3  
M3  df1|df2|df3            3  
M4          df1            1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) on a list of the input DafaFrames. This will work on any number of input DataFrames (not just 3):

```
# dataframes will be later named in order: 1->2->3
# you can easily tweak this solution to use a dictionary
# and custom names if desired
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

out = (pd
 .concat([d.set_index('ID').assign(ID=f'df{i}')
          for i,d in enumerate(dfs, start=1)], axis=1)
 .assign(**{'match': lambda d: d[['ID']].agg(lambda x: '|'.join(x.dropna()),
                                             axis=1),
            'No of matches': lambda d: d[['ID']].notna().sum(axis=1)
           })
 .drop('ID', axis=1).reset_index()
)
```

*NB. this approach uses a temporary `ID` column, make sure it is not present in any of the input DataFrame's column. You can chose another name for safety if needed.*

output:

```
   ID    Movie  Actor    type         highlight  no of parts  co-star award        match  No of matches
0  M1  Top gun    Tom  Action     Flight school          NaN      NaN   NaN      df1|df2              2
1  M2     Thor  Chris   SciFi  Love and thunder          3.0  portman   yes  df1|df2|df3              3
2  M3   Batman   Bale   Comic       I am Batman          3.0   neeson   yes  df1|df2|df3              3
3  M4   MadMax    Tom   SciFi               NaN          NaN      NaN   NaN          df1              1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one too; **merging with reduce-lambda**

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='ID',how='outer'), dfs)
df_temp = df_final[[df1.columns[1],df2.columns[1],df3.columns[1]]]
df_final["match"] = df_temp.apply(lambda x: "|".join(["df"+str(idx+1) for idx,i in enumerate(x) if pd.isna(i)==False]),axis=1)
df_final["No of match"] = df_final["match"].apply(lambda x: x.count("|")+1)
```

Output;

```
   ID    Movie  Actor    type  ...  co-star  award        match No of match
0  M1  Top gun    Tom  Action  ...      NaN    NaN      df1|df2           2
1  M2     Thor  Chris   SciFi  ...  portman    yes  df1|df2|df3           3
2  M3   Batman   Bale   Comic  ...   neeson    yes  df1|df2|df3           3
3  M4   MadMax    Tom   SciFi  ...      NaN    NaN          df1           1
```